# Highcharts library UI glitches

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am experiencing some extreme usage of the highcharts library. Maybe someone can help with these cases.
My scenario is that i execute different queries in the database and based on that data i have to plot a chart. The data is highly dynamic in nature . Also based on the data, i have to display certain limits (that are computed based on the data) . These limits are ploted using 'plotLines' option on the Oy axis. These lines have to appear all the time , so in order to do this i manually compute the max and min on the Oy axis so that the highcharts can display the lines all the time.
Based on this, i have two extreme cases:

1) The first one is described by this fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/314mgzwn/ . 
The text label of one of my lines is not visible because of a line from the chart that is displayed automatically by the chart (line named USL in the fiddle) . Is there any way i can bypass this ?

2) The second scenario is related to the fact that i may have a lot of data on the Ox axis. In this case, as seen in the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ghx6e07r/ the data is not displayed, only the tooltip appears when i go with the mouse over this area. When i zoom manually the data starts to appear. Is there any way i can show the data from start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The lines which cover the plot area are grid lines. They can be controlled in the same way as ticks (grid lines extend ticks). They have [z-index](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridZIndex) property (also plot lines have [it](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines.zIndex)).

```
  propertyObjectY = {
value: 0,
color: '',
dashStyle: 'Solid',
width: 2,
label: {
  text: ''
},
zIndex: 2
}
```

Set zIndex to 2, so the plot lines will be drawn on top of the grid lines.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/314mgzwn/3/

2) When your data are densed, the marker will not be rendered by default, so you need to enable them manually.

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ghx6e07r/2/

The second case in that example are null values, which will not be connected by lines unless you set [connectNulls](http://connectNulls) property to true.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ghx6e07r/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following for scenario-1 :

```
 propertyObjectY = {
  value: 0,
  color: '',
 // dashStyle: 'Solid',
  width: 0,
  label: {
    text: ''
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/314mgzwn/1/)

Scenario-2 , The problem is that you have "null" points as well. In highcharts null points not get connected by default. to connect them use

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        connectNulls: true
    }
},
```

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ghx6e07r/1/)

Now, since there is a lot of data-points so your graph will be shown messy.if you zoom the graph it looks usual.